# EntityFramework não reconhece transformação Web Config

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Na minha solução `C#`, utilizo transformação `Web.config` para conectar um ambiente de dados especifico, mas estou tendo um problema com `EntityFramework` que não consegue reconhecer `string de conexão` ***transformada***, só reconhece o `Web.config` **principal**.

Como resolver esse problema?

*Exemplo de codigos abaixo:*

Arquivo `web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>     
    <add name="ConexCobranca" connectionString="Data Source=BBBBBBB;Initial Catalog=CapCob;User ID=xxxyyy;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DbCobCapEntidades" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloCobranca.csdl|res://*/ModeloCobranca.ssdl|res://*/ModeloCobranca.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BBBBBBB;initial catalog=CapCob;persist security info=True;user ID=xxxyyy;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

---

Arquivo `web.HML.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConexCobranca" connectionString="Data Source=ABCDEF;Initial Catalog=CapCob;User ID=USERA;Password=xxx" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    <add name="DbCobEntidades" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloCobranca.csdl|res://*/ModeloCobranca.ssdl|res://*/ModeloCobranca.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ABCDEF;initial catalog=CapCob;persist security info=True;user ID=USERA;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

`Cobranca.EDMX`

```
public partial class DbCobEntidades : ObjectContext
{
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new DbCobEntidades object using the connection string found in the 'DbCobEntidades' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public DbCobEntidades() : base("name=DbCobEntidades", "DbCobEntidades")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: Poste o seu WebConfig, Codigos que tem no seu projeto!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic postei!

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo `web.HML.config`, seria no caso um arquivo de configuração de sua aplicação quando fosse gerado uma publicação (compilação) do seu projeto, então, quando fosse gerado uma compilação a partir desse `web.HML.config`, é criado um `Web.config` com as especificações de `web.HML.config`.

Segundo o [***link***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

*Salvar e fechar o arquivo de transformação.*

*Quando você implantar o Webaplicativo usando configuração da compilação selecionada e usando um pacote de implantação publicação com um clique, arquivo Web.config é transformado de acordo com suas especificações.*

***Referencia:*** [Como: Transformar o Web.config quando implantar um projeto de aplicativo Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Nesse mesmo texto diz que o Visual Studio cria um arquivo de configuração padrão para ***Debug*** e ***Release***, mas, nada impede que seja criado o seu próprio, mas, que isso só é modificado quando gerado uma compilação do projeto com a escolha do arquivo de configuração do Visual Studio(`Web.config`) ou algum outro arquivo criado pelo desenvolvedor.

Para fazer uma publicação do seu projeto clique com o botão direito no nome do seu projeto e no sub menu selecione **Publish** e siga o passo a passo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nos testes executados, realmente não funciona, mas, quando gerei a compilação do projeto (`Publish`) percebi que ele fez a transformação para `Web.Config` que eu **selecionei**.

*Os arquivos criados adicionais, serviram então, como configuração por exemplo para um determinado servidor que possui conexão com banco diferente do que está na maquina local de desenvolvimento sendo útil já visto que as configuração de banco quando criamos as páginas quase nunca são iguais do servidor, seria uma forma de criação de acordo com o servidor utilizado.*

Links:

- [Como: Transformar o Web.config quando implantar um projeto de aplicativo Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx)
- [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)
- [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How do I use Web.Config transform on my connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366091/how-do-i-use-web-config-transform-on-my-connection-strings)
- [How to use web.config transforms to replace appSettings and connectionStrings?](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings)